# How to generate random iOS User Events with Automation?

Tags: ios, automation, touch, instruments

When developing on Android we have something called Monkey, it generates random user events and sends them to the device. Its very useful to stress test the app.
Is there something similar for iOS?

Thanks in advance,
Paulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've already found an answer in 4 months, but for a case:
[UIAutomation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009771-CH1-SW1) can be used for this (but you'll have to create a monkey yourself)